# Why does git think I'm 11 commits behind, when I only see two commits?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a branch tracking a remote branch.  Remote branch is at commit `a5d6f33`.  Local branch is at `4a656e7`.  If I check out a new branch tracking the remote, putting it at `a5d6f33`, I see the following in the log:

```
* a5d6f33
|
* d335c4c
|
* 4a656e7
|
* 9c744ca
|
* 49e35d0
```

If I view it in SourceTree, I get the following:

```
* a5d6f33 (4a656e7, d335c4c)
|\
| * d335c4c [feature/b]
| |
* 4a656e7 (49e35d0, 9c744ca)
|\|
* 49e35d0
| |\
:/  * 9c744ca [feature/a]
* f21f262 
|   :
* 125ba89
|   * edaf06e
| /
* f5df392
```

Basically, `feature/a` was branched from `f5df392`, and merged in at `4a656e7`.  `feature/b` was branched from `f21f262`, and merged in at `a5d6f33`.  There were other commits prior to those (represented by colons), but none appear relevant to this (`feature/b` only has one commit, all the other commits come before the sequence in question; the two feature branches were started with a single commit in-between their root branch point, and merged one after the other).

Both branches merged clean.  If `49e35d0` already has all of the changes in `125ba89` and `f21f262` and everything else leading up to `4a656e7`, to me, there should be two new commits (`d335c4c` and `a5d6f33`) missing from my local branch tracking the remote.

Where are the other 9 coming from?  Is there a way to find where git is getting this 11 count from?  If I do a diff between local and remote, I only see the modifications in the single feature/b commit.

Comment: What do you see if you run `git log HEAD..origin`?

Comment: It's kinda hard to tell from that graph in which side is each commit. Maybe if you move those to the left instead of keeping everything in the right would clarify a little. Also, maybe use capital letters like `A`, `B`, `C`... instead of hash values.

Comment: any chance you could provide a `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --branches --all` ? this will help 'clean up' the graph to make it easier to read

Answer (score 2):

The "ahead" and "behind" counts are from the result of:

```
git rev-list --count <exclude>..<include>
```

(note: two dots) which is run *twice*, with `<exclude>` and `<include>` swapped; or equivalently, from the result of:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right HEAD...<upstream>
```

(note: three dots this time, and I changed the names a bit).  This does not really change the question, but—I hope—reframes it slightly to make the answer make more sense.  There are several parts to the answer as well, but in the end, it's because merges tend to add a lot to *reachability*.

#### What are these exclude/include things with the two dot syntax?

The problem with a Git branch name is that it only names *one* commit.  We want "a branch" to mean *many* commits.  Well, that is, *sometimes* we want that, and sometimes we only want *one* commit.  The one commit is the *tip* of the branch, and the many-commits are some subset of all commits *reachable from* the tip commit.  (See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

This "reachability" concept is at the core of a lot of Git operations.  The way it works is very simple, with one wrinkle at *merge commits*: each commit records its *parent* commit, which is "the commit that *was* the branch tip, just before we made *this* commit."

That is, if we start with a simple repository with just three commits, it might look like this:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

(I've replaced Git's big ugly hash IDs—the ones Git shows you now and then, and often abbreviates—with single letters, since `3bc53220cb2dcf709f7a027a3f526befd021d858` is basically incomprehensible.  This means I can only draw 26 commits, but that should be plenty for illustration.)  The *branch name* `master` has `C`'s ID in it.  We say that the name `master` *points to* commit `C`.  Commit `C`, though, actually has `B`'s ID right inside `C`, and we say that `C` *points to* `B`.  Likewise, `B` points to `A`, but `A` is the very first commit we ever made, so it cannot and does not point anywhere at all.  This means that `A` is a *root commit*.

To add a new commit `D`, Git writes out the commit itself with the ID of commit `C` inside it, so that `D` points back to `C`.  Then it changes the name `master` to have `D`'s new ID, so that `master` points to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

Note that all of Git's internal arrows are backwards!  We start with the most recent commit, and work back through history.  This allows Git to never touch any existing commit.  Mostly, we don't have to care, though, so instead of drawing all the internal arrows, we can just draw lines connecting each commit to its parent(s), and *remember* that Git works backwards.

This parent linkage gives you a nice linear structure: commit (biguglyhash1) has commit (biguglyhash2) as its parent, and that commit has (biguglyhash3) as its parent, and so on.  A *branch* in this linkage-of-commits occurs when two *different* commits have the *same* parent:

```
...--C--D
      \
       E
```

Here, commit `D` points back to `C`, but so does commit `E`.  (Note that when we made commit `C` we probably had no idea it would have *two* children.  Since the internal arrows all point backwards, though, we don't have to change `C` to record its children; it's sufficient to have both `D` and `E` remember `C` as their parent.  This holds no matter how many children we may eventually add.)

Anyway, we work for a while and get some more commits, on both branches—let's put in a branch *name* while we are at it:

```
A--B--C--D-------I   <-- master
       \
        E--F--G--H   <-- sidebr
```

It's obvious that commits `A-B-C` are all on branch `master` ... but that's only *obvious* because that's how we started out and that's how we drew this.  What if we re-draw the graph a bit, like this?

```
     C--D-------I   <-- master
    / \
A--B   E--F--G--H   <-- sidebr
```

Now it seems like `A` and `B` are on `sidebr`.  Or, we could use this drawing, which might be the most accurate of all:

```
        D--------I   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        E--F--G--H   <-- sidebr
```

Now it seems like maybe `A-B-C` aren't on either branch, or—maybe—are on *both* branches.  And that's the right answer for Git: `A-B-C` are in fact on *both branches*.

More precisely, if we start at the *tip* commit of either branch, `I` for master and `H` for `sidebr`, we work our way backwards (leftwards, in these graphs; with `git log --graph` and other drawings it's often downwards or upwards depending on who and what drew it) from each commit to its parent.  As we go, each commit we find is "on"—or "contained in"—the branch.  Since `C` is *reachable from* either tip, it's *on both branches*.

#### But a lot of the time we don't *want* all the commits

Ultimately, then, if you name a *branch tip*, that can select every commit all the way back to the *root* commit.  The name `sidebr` could mean commits all the way back to `A`.  But most of the time, we don't *want* all those commits.  Given:

```
        D--------I   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        E--F--G--H   <-- sidebr
```

we would like to say: "Look at commits that are reachable from `sidebr`, but stop looking at commits that are reachable from `master`."  This is why Git has the two-dot syntax:

```
master..sidebr
```

literally means "commits reachable from `sidebr`, excluding commits reachable from `master`".  In other words, this names commits `E-F-G-H`, and not any of `A-B-C`.  (It also excludes `D` and `I`, which is really easy since they were never included in the first place.)

There are a bunch of ways to visualize this, but my favorite is to color in the commits, as if with a highlighter.  We mark the tip of the "exclude" branch in red, and the tip of the "include" branch in green.  We extend the red marker back to all its appropriate parents, and the green marker back to all its appropriate parents.  Just make sure that either red *overwrites* green, or that you never color in green once you've done all the red ones first.  When you are done, all the green commits are the ones selected.

Now, this is all fine and should be reasonably obvious, but let's make the graph a bit more complicated.  Let's add `origin/master`, and say that it points to commit `D`, which forces me to re-draw the graph again:

```
        D            <-- origin/master
       / \
A--B--C   I          <-- master
       \
        E--F--G--H   <-- sidebr
```

That is, we have one commit on our `master` that we added, and that we have not yet pushed up to `origin`; and four commits on our `sidebr`.  Let's add a *merge commit* now, by merging `sidebr` *into* `master` with `git checkout master; git merge sidebr`:

```
        D              <-- origin/master
       / \
A--B--C   I--------J   <-- master
       \          /
        E--F--G--H     <-- sidebr
```

This creates a new *merge commit* `J`.  The thing that makes it a merge commit—aside from using `git merge` to make it, that is—is that it has *two* parents instead of just one.  The *first* parent of `J` is `I`, in the usual way, but the *second* parent of `J` is `H`: the tip of `sidebr`.

This new merge commit `J` makes the name `master` "reach" all of the `sidebr` commits, through that second parent.  When we go to color in reachable and exclude commits, we must follow *all* the parents of a merge, simultaneously (or as close as we can to that), until the branches re-join wherever they forked earlier.

(As an aside, the *merge base* of `I` and `H` is commit `C`.  Commit `C` is where the branches first re-join.  That's really easy to see in the diagrams from before we added `origin/master`.  **Adding a label to the graph never alters the graph itself**, and the merge base of any two commits is *determined by the graph*.  When you are merging, the merge base is critical to how the merge will be done, so it's important to *draw the graph* by starting from the two tip commits and working back to where they first come together.  That's what Git will do: find the merge base, then diff the merge base against each tip commit.)

So, consider what `origin/master..master` meant both before and after the merge.  Before the merge, we would paint some commits red, based on what we can reach from `origin/master`.  Those are commits `A-B-C-D`.  We'd paint other commits green, based on what we can reach from `master`: that's `A-B-C-D-I`.  The `git rev-list` command normally prints out the ID of each found commit, but with `--count`, it just counts them up.  So:

```
git rev-list origin/master..master
```

will count just one "green commit" `I` and print `1`.

*After the merge*, though, the name `master` names commits `A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J`.  We only *added* one commit, `J`, but `J` *brought in* commits `E-F-G-H`.  We color them red and green as before—try it out on a whiteboard, or on paper, or at least in your head—and count the commits, and instead of two, we get six.  So:

```
git rev-list origin/master..master
```

will now print `6`.

#### How you can be both ahead and behind

We just did this with a case where `master` winds up only *ahead of* `origin/master`, but let's "erase the merge" for a moment, and look at `master` vs `sidebr`, without bothering with `origin/master`:

```
        D--------I   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        E--F--G--H   <-- sidebr
```

If we count commits on `master`, excluding commits on `sidebr`, with `sidebr..master`, we will count commits `D` and `I`, which gets us the number 2.  If we count commits on `sidebr` while excluding `master`, i.e., `master..sidebr`, we count `E-F-G-H` and get 4.  That's why we want to do both, to see if there are commits on one branch that aren't on the other, in both directions.

Git can do this for us all at once using the three-dot syntax, `master...sidebr` or `sidebr...master`.  This means "commits that are reachable from either tip, but *not* reachable from *both*."  That is, we want commits `D` and `I` to be colored green, and `E-F-G-H` to be colored green, but we want want `A-B-C`, which are on both branches, to be red / stopped-out.  The three-dot syntax does that; if we just count the resulting set, it has six commits (`D-I` plus `E-F-G-H`).  Adding `--left-right` tells Git to remember for us which *side* they came in from, and adding `--count` counts the two sides, so this prints both 2 and 4.  The number on the left is the number of commits on the left branch, and the number on the right is the number of commits on the right branch.  (Note that swapping the names swaps the counts.)

We can do the same thing with `master` and `origin/master`:

```
git rev-list --left-right --count origin/master..master
```

The left hand count will be commits that are on `origin/master` that are not on `master`, and the right hand count will be commits on `master` that are not on `origin/master`.  Or, swap the names around and we get swapped counts.

#### What it means to be ahead and/or behind

Let's return to the "after the merge" graph:

```
        D              <-- origin/master
       / \
A--B--C   I--------J   <-- master
       \          /
        E--F--G--H     <-- sidebr
```

If we count commits on `origin/master` and `master`, we already noted that `master` was `6 ahead` of `origin/master`.  That happened because `master` was `1 ahead`, then we added merge commit `J` which brought in four more commits = `6 ahead`.

If we now run `git fetch origin` to pick up any new commits *they* have, we might find that `origin` got a new commit on *its* master.  Let's call that commit `K`, and draw it in:

```
        D----------K   <-- origin/master
       / \
A--B--C   I--------J   <-- master
       \          /
        E--F--G--H     <-- sidebr
```

Now let's count both sides of `master...origin/master`.  We get the same six on the left side—six commits reachable from `master` that are not reachable from `origin/master`—but this time, we get one commit, `K`, on the right side.  So our `master` is now `6 ahead, 1 behind` of our `origin/master`, which is our Git's new memory of where `master` is on `origin`.

#### The `<upstream>` in `HEAD...<upstream>`

For Git to count these commits for you, Git needs to know *what names to use* in your repository when doing these `git rev-list --count` operations.

The *current branch* is easy, because the file `HEAD` records the name of the current branch.  (Try it yourself:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

This, in fact, is exactly what it means to be `on branch master`, as `git status` will say.)  But what should the other half of `master...something` or `something...master` *be*?

For this, Git uses the *upstream* of the branch.  This upstream is created automatically when you do:

```
git checkout somebranch
```

and there's an `origin/somebranch` in your repository.  In this case, Git creates a new local `somebranch` pointing to the *same commit* as your `origin/somebranch`, which is a *remote-tracking branch name*.  A remote-tracking branch is one whose name is like `origin/master`, i.e., the name of a remote `origin`, plus a slash, plus a branch name retrieved from the remote.  Your Git uses these names to remember what you last got from, or gave to, that remote.  Running `git fetch origin` updates all your `origin/*` names (and is otherwise totally safe—you can `git fetch` at any time without disrupting things).

In some cases, like when you create your own branch `sidebr` that doesn't *have* an `origin/sidebr` yet, you will want to use:

```
git push -u origin somebr
```

or:

```
git push --set-upstream origin somebr
```

This tells your Git that once `origin`'s Git has its own `sidebr` so that your Git remembers that as `origin/sidebr`, *then* your Git should set `origin/sidebr` as the upstream for your `sidebr`.

At any time, you can run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/whatever
```

to *change* your current branch's upstream setting to `origin/whatever`.  But there is only one upstream per branch, so you probably want to leave it set to `origin/same-name`.

To *see* your current branch's upstream:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u}
```

or:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}
```

(you may need to quote the `@{u}` part to protect it from your shell: sh and bash are OK with this, but csh/tcsh try to do brace expansion, and zsh might as well).  Try them out to see the difference between `--abbrev-ref` and `--symbolic-full-name`.  Note that the current branch must have an upstream for `@{u}` to work.  (While there's only *one* upstream, you can have *no* upstream instead.)

Answer (score 0):

To check the commits on current local branch which behind origin, you can use:

```
git log branchname..origin/branchname --oneline
```

If `git status` says there have 11 commits behind, you will find the 11 commits here.